# Transformation with namespace

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

**InputXML:**

```
<json:object xmlns:json="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/2009/jsonx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <json:object name="Customers">
        <json:array name="Order">
            <json:object>
                <json:string name="Name">john</json:string>
                <json:string name="Password">Doe</json:string>
            </json:object>
            <json:object>
                <json:string name="Name">Adam</json:string>
                <json:string name="Password">eve</json:string>
            </json:object>
        </json:array> 
    </json:object>
</json:object>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" xmlns:tns="http://some-other-namespace" xmlns:json="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/2009/jsonx" exclude-result-prefixes="json">
    <xsl:template match="/json:object">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="json:array[@name]">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="json:object[@name]">
        <xsl:element name="{@name}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="json:object">
        <xsl:element name="{../@name}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="json:string[@name]">
        <xsl:element name="{@name}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Actual output:**

```
<Customers>
    <Order>
        <Name>john</Name>
        <Password>Doe</Password>
    </Order>
    <Order>
        <Name>Adam</Name>
        <Password>eve</Password>
    </Order>
</Customers>
```

**Desired Output:**

```
<Customers xmlns:tns="http://some-other-namespace">
    <Order>
        <Name>john</Name>
        <Password>Doe</Password>
    </Order>
    <Order>
        <Name>Adam</Name>
        <Password>eve</Password>
    </Order>
</Customers>
```

I know we can do identity transform in another xsl by passing Actual output as its input and obtain my Desired Output.

But I want to do everything in one single styleesheet. How to achieve that using single xsl

Comment: Your expected result makes very little sense. The only difference between it and the actual output is an **unused** namespace declaration. It shouldn't make any difference at all to the receiving application.

Comment: i agree. But I want to use that for schema validation

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to generate a namespace declaration that isn't actually used in any element or attribute name, and that doesn't appear in the source document, you can use the `xsl:namespace` instruction (a rather specialized instruction that exists only for this obscure purpose).

Comment: When I make a suggestion like that, I assume you will go to your favourite XSLT textbook and look it up - I'm not going to give a tutorial. You can use it just like xsl:attribute.